# notresponding dialog box is showing after clicking on button

Tags: java, android

already had a login procedure for my app but trying to integrate with facebook graph api
if i tried to login with FB ,app is not accepting.help
here i am pasting the FB button code

```
case R.id.fbButton:
            authenticateOnFacebook();
            sendFacebookIdToServer(APP_ID, getApplicationContext());
            break;
```

the authenticate method for facebook,in this i am using getcredentials method also .

```
public void authenticateOnFacebook()
     {
        try{
            String[] permissions={"user_birthday", "email"};
            facebook.authorize(this.activity, permissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    try{
                        String facebookId = getCredentials((String) values.get("access_token"));
                        sendFacebookIdToServer(facebookId, context);
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     protected String getCredentials(String token) {
        JSONObject jObject=null;
        String facebookId = null; 

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, token);

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me", params));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(jObject!=null)
        {
            try {  
                facebookId = jObject.getString("id");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return facebookId;
    }
```

and for sending request to my server to authenticate i am using this method

```
public void sendFacebookIdToServer(String facebookId, Context context){
        String accessToken = null;
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        DatabaseUtility dao = new DatabaseUtility(helper);
        try {
            accessToken = dao.getAccessToken();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Map<String , String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put(Constants.FACEBOOK_ID, facebookId);
        params.put(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM, accessToken);
        Status status = null;
        try {
            status = Utils.addFacebookAccount(params, context);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if((status != null) && (status.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SUCCESS))){
            navigateNowLisnScreenWithSuccess();
        }
     }

    private void navigateNowLisnScreenWithSuccess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(context,TabView.class);
        startActivity(i);   
    }
```

Logcat:

```
01-17 10:34:26.004: W/System.err(575): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument
01-17 10:34:26.004: W/System.err(575):  at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:92)
01-17 10:34:26.004: W/System.err(575):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.startDialogAuth(Facebook.java:308)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:207)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at com.lisnx.activity.LoginActivity.authenticateOnFacebook(LoginActivity.java:164)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at com.lisnx.activity.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:262)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-17 10:34:26.014: W/System.err(575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 10:34:26.024: W/System.err(575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 10:34:26.024: W/System.err(575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 10:34:26.024: W/System.err(575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 10:34:26.024: W/System.err(575):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 10:34:26.045: W/System.err(575): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-17 10:34:26.045: W/System.err(575):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:434)
01-17 10:34:26.045: W/System.err(575):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
01-17 10:34:26.045: W/System.err(575):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
01-17 10:34:26.045: W/System.err(575):  at com.lisnx.dao.TokenDao.getAccessToken(TokenDao.java:59)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at com.lisnx.dao.DatabaseUtility.getAccessToken(DatabaseUtility.java:111)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at com.lisnx.activity.LoginActivity.sendFacebookIdToServer(LoginActivity.java:223)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at com.lisnx.activity.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:263)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-17 10:34:26.054: W/System.err(575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 10:34:26.064: W/System.err(575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 10:34:26.064: W/System.err(575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 10:34:26.064: W/System.err(575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 10:34:26.064: W/System.err(575):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 10:34:26.794: D/dalvikvm(575): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 14% free 7244K/8327K, paused 5ms+4ms
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=10 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=151 violation=2
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1074)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:94)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at com.android.internal.os.AtomicFile.startWrite(AtomicFile.java:59)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.content.SyncStorageEngine.writeStatusLocked(SyncStorageEngine.java:1906)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.content.SyncStorageEngine.handleMessage(SyncStorageEngine.java:336)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=6 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=151 violation=1
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1048)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:178)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:447)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.content.SyncStorageEngine.writeStatusLocked(SyncStorageEngine.java:1915)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.content.SyncStorageEngine.handleMessage(SyncStorageEngine.java:336)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 10:34:27.254: D/StrictMode(77):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=1 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=151 violation=1
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1048)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.fsync(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(FileDescriptor.java:71)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.FileUtils.sync(FileUtils.java:111)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at com.android.internal.os.AtomicFile.finishWrite(AtomicFile.java:80)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.content.SyncStorageEngine.writeStatusLocked(SyncStorageEngine.java:1918)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.content.SyncStorageEngine.handleMessage(SyncStorageEngine.java:336)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 10:34:27.264: D/StrictMode(77):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:744)
```

Comment: I don't know the API, but the error says that a context is invalid.  My guess is you either didn't call an initialization function that took a Context, or you passed the wrong type (the application context and it needed the activity, for example).

Comment: Facebook graph api,i would like to get the credentials from facebook so the getting the credentials part is correct?bcz i am thinking there is a problem in my code in that placce

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0" which may cause the issue.